# How to plot distributions for multiple columns on one graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, data-science

- I want to create a visualization of the distribution of the attributes across gender in **one** graph. Is there a way to do that in Python?
- I used `px.boxplot`, but I can only do one column at a time.

```py
df.head():

 gender amb1_1 intel1_1 attr1_1 sinc1_1 shar1_1
0   0   15.0    20.0    15.0    20.0    15.0
1   0   15.0    20.0    15.0    20.0    15.0
2   0   15.0    20.0    15.0    20.0    15.0
3   0   15.0    20.0    15.0    20.0    15.0
4   0   15.0    20.0    15.0    20.0    15.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert the dataframe to long format with [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- Plot with [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and use `hue='gender'`

  - [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is a Python data visualization library based on `matplotlib`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
data = {'gender': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        'amb1_1': [15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0],
        'intel1_1': [25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0],
        'attr1_1': [15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0],
        'sinc1_1': [25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0],
        'shar1_1': [15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to long
dfl = df.set_index('gender').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'groups', 0: 'values'})

# plot
p = sns.boxplot(x='groups', y='values', data=dfl, hue='gender')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### With `plotly`

- The dataframe needs to be long, like `dfl` from the last example
- With the example code from [Choosing The Algorithm For Computing Quartiles](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#choosing-the-algorithm-for-computing-quartiles)

```py
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot

fig = px.box(dfl, x="groups", y="values", color="gender")
plot(fig)
```

[image]